# Installed GarageBand Jam Pack 2 Remix Tools but can't find it

Tags: garageband

The installer installed it to my hard drive but I don't see an icon that I'm supposed to click on to access it.  Can anyone help me understand this

Answer (score 1):

You access the instruments and loops from within the GarageBand application. Instruments will be added to the pane on the right, under the Software Instruments: Browse tab.

Loops will be in the Loop Browser. In GarageBand, pull down the Control menu and choose "Show Loop Browser".

[image]

[image: enter link description here]

Answer (score 0):

The Jam Pack installs additional loops etc. which are accessible inside GarageBand only.