# How can I get more keyboard software instruments for GarageBand?

Tags: garageband, midi, audio

I've been using GarageBand to play my MIDI keyboard for a few years, just because of its built-in software instruments for keyboards. Now I'm thinking about purchasing some jam packs only for the extra keyboard software instruments.

Which ones should I buy? Are there any more places or third-party software where I can get more keyboard instruments? I really want to have a huge selection of keyboard sounds, but don't know where or how to get them.

Comment: Consider asking this question on http://avp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Brad this question is about Apple software, so there's no reason it should be moved to another site unless it does not get answered here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many third-party virtual keyboard instruments. Do a search at the kvraudio.com virtual instrument news site. Anything that is in Audio Unit (AU) format will work with GarageBand. [Here is a search result](http://www.kvraudio.com/get.php?mode=results&st=adv&soft%5B%5D=i&type%5B%5D=29&type%5B%5D=7&type%5B%5D=8&type%5B%5D=37&type%5B%5D=1&type%5B%5D=5&type%5B%5D=34&type%5B%5D=42&type%5B%5D=57&type%5B%5D=24&type%5B%5D=47&type%5B%5D=92&type%5B%5D=35&type%5B%5D=48&type%5B%5D=30&type%5B%5D=2&f%5B%5D=au&osx=1&free=1&com=1&sf=0&receptor=&de=0&sort=1&rpp=15) I have prepared for you.

Popular products you might consider:

Anything by [Native Instruments](http://www.native-instruments.com/#/en/products/?category=1649)

[Pianoteq](http://www.pianoteq.com/catalog)

Buying Apple **Logic Express** or **Logic Studio** will give you all the Apple Jam Pack sounds in one purchase, with many other features besides. [Apple Logic Express](http://www.apple.com/logicexpress/plug-ins.html#studio-instruments) and [Logic Studio](http://www.apple.com/logicstudio/plug-ins/#studio-instruments).

Finally, read [**Keyboard Magazine**](http://keyboardmag.com/). They provide a lot of coverage and reviews of products in this category.

Comment: Thanks, Wheat. Since I'm sill new to this kind of third-party stuff, could you please explain me how should I get these "plugins" to work with GarageBand? They're often .component, .vst or .dpa files. It's my very first time doing this :)

Comment: .vst won't work with GarageBand. Only Audio Unit (AU) format will work. When you install these instruments, they become available in GarageBand in the Software Instruments pane on the right, under the Edit tab, under Sound Generator: Audio Unit Modules.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21836/installed-garageband-jam-pack-2-remix-tools-but-cant-find-it

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/GarageBand-Power-Comprehensive-Recording-Podcasting/dp/1435459628/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1313592820&sr=8-1

Comment: Oder wenn Sie Deutsch lesen würden: http://www.amazon.de/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_13?__mk_de_DE=%C5M%C5Z%D5%D1&url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=garageband+11&sprefix=garageband+11

Answer (score 0):

Best buy is simply Apple MainStage3, for 30 USD you get 60GB of content that works in GarageBand.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEJvJBLtMeY

Apply symlink trick to get them all:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/280434/203343