# GarageBand 10.1.1 Removed MainStage Instruments

Tags: audio, garageband, instruments

After updating to GarageBand 10.1.1, all the instruments I've downloaded from MainStage 3 have disappeared from the instrument library. They still seem to be in `/Library/Application Support/GarageBand/Instrument Library/Sampler/Sampler Instruments`, but they're not showing up in the list. Any projects with the instruments, however, play perfectly with them.

I'm not talking about Jam Packs here; they're still right there in the "Legacy" category. I'm talking about things like the expanded orchestral strings, world music, etc. How can I get these back?

[Topic on the Apple website.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7526588)

Comment: Does the solution mentioned in the Apple Forum you cite not work for you?

Answer (score 2):

To restore all your MainStage3 instruments do this trick which will add new root folder "User patches" in the Instrument selector:

- Quit Garageband
- Open Terminal
- Type these three commands (all are one lines):

  - `mkdir "$HOME/Music/Audio Music Apps/Patches/Instrument"`
  - `ln -s "/Applications/MainStage 3.app/Contents/Resources/Patches/Instrument" "$HOME/Music/Audio Music Apps/Patches/Instrument/Mainstage"`
  - `exit`
- Close Terminal and start GarageBand
- Locate Mainstage3 instruments in the "User patches" area or use search box

Downside is some patches are now showed twice, but this does not mean your instruments occupy more space or disk or anything. In the steps above, you actually made a symlink from user patch directory into MainStage3 program patch directory, so GarageBand can always access it. This will alway work not matter how many times you update any of the two programs.

Extra trick: You can edit any patch and save it into Patches/Instrument directory and it will also show up (only first strip channel). This works with all Logic Pro X instruments, including Alchemy and others!

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed some instruments that have gone missing, such as the Bosendorfer Piano. Some of them I couldnt seem to get back, but try reinstalling them (like you did when you first got Mainstage)